# Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"post\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"USER\"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

This error occurs in Postman when I try to get all my posts.

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"post\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "post",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"post\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"USER\""
}
```

This is my Post Schema below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    heading:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    confess:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
   
   postedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "USER"
    },
});

const Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('POST', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

And this is my post router:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authenticate = require("../middleware/authenticate");
require('../db/connection');
const Post = require('../models/postSchema');

router.get('/post',authenticate,async (req,res)=>{
    Post.find({})
    .populate("postedBy","_id username")
    .then(posts=>{
        res.json(posts)
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})

router.post('/write',authenticate,async(req,res) =>{
    const{heading,confess} = req.body;
    if(!heading || !confess){
        return res.status(422).json({errror : "Fill all the columns"});
    }
   req.rootUser.password = undefined
   req.rootUser.cpassword = undefined
        const post = new Post({heading,confess,postedBy:req.rootUser});
        console.log(req.rootUser);
    await post.save();
     res.status(201).json({message:"done"});
    
} );

router.get('/myprofile',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Post.find({postedBy:req.rootUser._id})
    .populate("postedBy","_id username")
    .then(mypost=>{
        res.json({mypost})
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})


router.put('/updatepost',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.postId),{
        $set:req.body,
    },{
        new:true
    }.exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(422).json({errror:err})
        }else{
            res.json(result)
        }
    })
})

router.delete('/deletepost',authenticate,(req,res)=>{
    Post.findByIdAndDelete(req.body.postId).exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(422).json({errror:err})
        }else{
            res.json(result)
        }
    })
})

router.get('/post/:id',async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id);
        res.status(200).json(post);
    }catch (err) {
        if (err.kind === "ObjectId") {
            return res.status(404).json({
                errors: [
                    {
                        msg: "User not found",
                        status: "404",
                    },
                ],
            });
        }
        next(err);
    }
})
 module.exports = router;
```

Problem: I'm getting the above error when I get localhost:5000/post in Postman.

```
      But when I apply this.
```

```
router.get('/post/allpost',authenticate,async (req,res)=>{
    Post.find({})
    .populate("postedBy","_id username")
    .then(posts=>{
        res.json(posts)
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

And get localhost:5000/post/allpost in Postman,
Then I don't get an Error, and all posts are shown.
Why the error is occurring and how to solve it.

Comment: there are lots of mistakes in your code, all the mongoose ops which needs id for querying you will need to pass an object with `id` not the value directly inside the function. do like this `findByIdAndUpdate({_id:value})` and for other ops which needs `id` for querying or updating collection

Comment: that I'll do when I create frontend but why this error is coming, plz help. Error is not because of things you mentioned

Comment: are you getting this error when you are trying use GET method on '/post' route?

Comment: yes when I GET localhost:5000/post on postman the error occurs

Comment: try removing {} from find method, The error says that you are trying to pass post inside _id field.

Comment: nothing happend same error, I even comment out all other routes than this one but error is coming still

Comment: the logic seems fine, since you are saying that you have commented out all the routes except `'/post'` , can you check by changing `'/post'` to any other route name.
Or you can try to await and check `const result = await Post.find({})` and then try 
`return res.json({result});`

Comment: Its done, there was a mistake in other route, Well thanks man.

Comment: what was the mistake? can you please tell, was it passing value incorrectly to mongoose methods?

Comment: no, in user router I was doing router.get( '/:id') that was the cause